# Comparing an url and a string

Tags: php

How do you compare a server request and a string in PHP?

I haven't done any web development in years and completely forgot.

```
<?php
        $min = 0; $max = 9;
        $index = 0; $pages = 2;

        for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++){
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php?id='.(string)$i ){
                $index = $i - 1;
                $min = $i * 9;
                $max = 2 * $min;
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Looks good to me, what's not working?

Comment: When i go to let's say /index.php?id=1, my if statement doesn't execute

Comment: If you are trying to figure out what "id" equals, use `$_GET['id']`

Comment: "a URL", right ? Not "an URL"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are trying to figure out what "id" equals, use `$_GET['id']`

```
if ($_GET['id'] === 1) {
    print "one";
}
```

Another option:

```
switch ($_GET['id']) {
    case 1:
        print "one";
        break;
    case default:
        print "invalid";
        break;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: it would be better to use strict comparison with strings `$_GET['id'] === '0'` because `'php' == 0 => true`. see [PHP type comparison tables](http://www.php.net/manual/de/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to compare URI parameters, you can do it like this:

```
$min = 0; $max = 9;
$index = 0; $pages = 2;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
    if ($_GET['id'] == $i) {
        $index = $i - 1;
        $min = $i * 9;
        $max = 2 * $min;
    }
}
```

$_GET and $_POST allow you to access parameters like `id=10&id2=100&name=aust` through `$_GET['id']`, `$_GET['id2']` and `$_GET['name']`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP your request will be in $_GET or $_POST (or $_REQUEST if you want it either way)